# PHP - Display No Code if PHP Value is Empty

Tags: php, echo, if-statement

I am using queries like this to pull in information from a database:

```
<p><strong>Show Description:</strong><br/><?php echo cimy_uef_sanitize_content(get_cimyFieldValue(1, 'show-description')); ?></p>
```

Is there any way to put the title (Show Description) into the PHP string and then, if the PHP field value is empty, to not show anything?

I think it would involve a PHP if/else statement, but I am not sure what the code should look like.

Thanks
Zach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard without seeing the code for those functions, but at a guess:

```
if (get_cimyFieldValue(1, 'show-description') != '')
    {
    echo "<p><strong>Show Description:</strong></p>" . cimy_uef_sanitize_content(get_cimyFieldValue(1, 'show-description'));
    }
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function for this purpose -

```
<p>
    <?php 
        $data = cimy_uef_sanitize_content(get_cimyFieldValue(1, 'show-description')); 

        if( !empty($data) )
        {
            echo "<strong>Show Description:</strong><br/>";
            echo $data;
        }
    ?>
</p>
```

According to the documentation, this function will return `true` if the `$data` variable is either -

```
1. "" (an empty string)
2. 0 (0 as an integer)
3. 0.0 (0 as a float)
4. "0" (0 as a string)
5. NULL
6. FALSE
7. array() (an empty array)
8. var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood You correctly, You need something like this:

```
<?php $title = cimy_uef_sanitize_content(get_cimyFieldValue(1, 'show-description')); ?>
<?php if(!empty($title)): ?>
<p>
    <strong>Show Description:</strong><br/>
    <?php echo $title; ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Not compiled, so there can be errors in code, but you get the point...